# how to retrieve multiple images from server and display one by one

Tags: android

In my app, i need to stream video and images from the server. If video is not available, Images should be retrieved and displayed in a photo gallery. I successfully did this part, but only with one image at a time. but this method is slow as its taking long time to load next image.

What i want to do is I pass the 4 urls ( 4 being the total number of images to be retrieved from server in this example) but display them in my imageview one by one by making use of a `Onclicklistener`. 
 Any suggestions please. How should i proceed? thanks

```
public class Imageviewing extends Activity implements  OnGestureListener{

    private static final String TAG = null;
    ImageView imView;
    String imageUrl="<myServerlink>";
    Random r= new Random();
    String urilink;
    private GestureDetector myGesture ;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 75;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageviewing);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // setContentView(R.layout.);
        // String

        urilink = intent.getExtras().getString("videouri");
        Log.e(TAG, urilink.toString());
        Button bt3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_imagebt);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(getImgListener);
        imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imview);
        myGesture = new GestureDetector(this);

    }
    View.OnClickListener getImgListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              finish();
          }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        return myGesture.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_imageviewing, menu);
        return true;
    }

     Bitmap bmImg;
        void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
              URL myFileUrl =null;          
              try {
                   myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
              try {
                   HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
                   conn.setDoInput(true);
                   conn.connect();
                   InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                   bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                   imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
                   Log.i("im url","Image to Imageview");
              } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                //do not do anything if the swipe does not reach a certain length of distance
               // if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) &gt; SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                   // return false;
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;

                // right to left swipe
                //if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() &gt; SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &amp;&amp; Math.abs(velocityX) &gt; SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    int i = r.nextInt(5-1)+1;
                    downloadFile(imageUrl+urilink+"-"+i+".jpg");
                    Log.i("im url",imageUrl+urilink+"-"+i+".jpg");
                    return false;

                }
               /* // left to right swipe
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() &gt; SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &amp;&amp; Math.abs(velocityX) &gt; SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ViewHistory();
                }*/
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
                float arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question for an example of how to efficiently load multiple images using what is known as lazy load.

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: storing image in memory could be bad, you should try save images in getCacheDir > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29